# How to extract list of pairs in a list enclosed by hash symbols?

Tags: python, for-loop

For example, from the 'tokens' list below, I want to extract the pair_list:

```
tokens = ['0', '#', 'a', 'b', '#', '#', 'c', '#',  '#', 'g', 'h', 'g', '#']

pair_list = [['a', 'b'], ['c'],  ['g', 'h', 'g']]
```

I was trying to do something like below, but hasn't succeeded:

```
hashToken_begin_found = True
hashToken_end_found = False

previous_token = None

pair_list = []

for token in tokens:

    if hashToken_begin_found and not hashToken_end_found and previous_token and previous_token == '#':
        hashToken_begin_found = False
    elif not hashToken_begin_found:
        if token == '#':
            hashToken_begin_found = True
            hashToken_end_found = True
        else:
            ...
```

ADDITION:

My actual problem is more complicated. What's inside the pair of # symbols are words in social media, like hashed phrases in twitter, but they are not English. I was simplified the problem to illustrate the problem. The logic would be something like I wrote: found the 'start' and 'end' of each # pair and extract it. In my data, anything in a pair of hash tags is a phrase, i.e. I live in #United States# and #New York#!. I need to get United States and New York. No regex. These words are already in a list.

Comment: How did it not work? What is your analysis? What debugging did you do?

Comment: Do you care about the case where you get 3+ consecutive hash tokens? What should the output be for `['0', '#', 'a', 'b', '#', '#', '#', 'c', '#', ...` ? If yes, you want to store `hash_tokens_seen` as in integer count, not just a boolean `hashToken_begin_found`/ `hashToken_end_found`.

Comment: It's twitter hash phrases. Assume it's always in the format of #...#, in which two hash tags identify an phrase.

Comment: @marlon. All you need to do to make your point about the other answer is to show a sample where it wouldn't work: like if you had text that was between the wrong parity hashes.

Comment: E.g., change the initial '0' to 'a'

Comment: @MadPhysicist You code seems working. What do you mean by the above comment?

Comment: I commented on the other answer to explain what I mean. The biggest problem is that you have poorly defined criteria and aren't taking the time to rewrite the question.

Comment: Most of those "pairs" aren't pairs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating the issue here. Think of the parser as a very simple state machine. You're either in a sublist or not. Every time you hit a hash, you toggle the state.

When entering a sublist, make a new list. When inside a sublist, append to the current list. That's about it. Here's a sample:

```
pair_list = []
in_pair = False
for token in tokens:
    if in_pair:
        if token == '#':
            in_pair = False
        else:
            pair_list[-1].append(token)
    elif token == '#':
        pair_list.append([])
        in_pair = True
```

Comment: I will be testing this one. Look like what i am looking for. I spent the whole afternoon but has failed so far.

Comment: I think this solution is working. I just need to find anything in pairs of the # symbols. It could be anything between a pair of #...#. In my data, anything in a pair of hash tags is a phrase.

Comment: This is a really smart solution. Is this going to be a good interview question?

Comment: @marlon. I wouldnt know

Answer (score 1):

You could try `itertools.groupby` in one single line:

```
from itertools import groupby
tokens = ['0', '#', 'a', 'b', '#', '#', 'c', '#',  '#', 'g', 'h', 'g', '#']
print([list(y) for x, y in itertools.groupby(tokens, key=lambda x: x.isalpha()) if x])
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['g', 'h', 'g']]
```

I group by the consecutive groups where the value is alphabetic.

If you want to use a `for` loop you could try:

```
l = [[]]
for i in tokens:
    if i.isalpha():
        l[-1].append(i)        
    else:
        if l[-1]:
            l.append([])
print(l[:-1])
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['g', 'h', 'g']]
```

Comment: Can you use a more traditional approach? My actual problem is more complicated. What's inside the pair of # symbols are words in social media, like hashed phrases in twitter, but they are not English. I was simplified the problem to illustrate the problem. So the itertools.groupby won't work. The logic would be something like I wrote: found a the start and end of each # pair and extract.

Comment: @marlon Well this solution solves your current case... You didn't specify the actual data.

Comment: @marlon Then I would suspect my for loop should work

Comment: @marlon. If the solution doesn't work for your issue as posted, I'd say your question is not very good: after all, you're responsible for creating an mcve sufficiently representative of your situation. You really can't fault the answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeap exactly!

Comment: Need to use '#' as the delimiter.

Comment: The issue here is not that the method isn't traditional. It's that it follows the letter of the poorly contrived question instead of the spirit, so to speak. Changing the first token to 'a' will invalidate this answer if the same result is expected.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hmm, I'd say the importance/role of the hash symbols was there from the start, both by the title saying *"enclosed by hash symbols"* and from the OP's code, and disregarding that and instead making up some other criterion *is* the fault of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv@xWBHpJAKYIXEfySEkKtwS6WNKQLrV8fs9EG9zA7C7OPCW@aFn@@hJgSLS/nV3ETvTzJVsiGZWC517PIeLjf/WSZqmukAbcHNxKz@gNh2gweeeX9/2IMAHIWyUX1baEhDBjtjGuBGNgmnB2zBfocvILIUzPdEILzD8VeFQxSZ613O1lbKmmtAUJET6p@6ZQ@)):

```
it = iter(tokens)
pair_list = []
while '#' in it:
    pair_list.append(list(iter(it.__next__, '#')))
```

Yet another ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/BCoMwDL33KwI7qCii7DKEHfcHYxcpo6th1kkttTL9etfq7DZYDi8vJO8lUZOpO7k/KD3Ppnug7OEIZZAFCQQ7B8zBzZcL8I2967uD2rNdQAmOCrlxXuVmQRNrzF2y@VtCKSGKCX1tRb9IKDF6KgjYELbOFvasRYtw1gOuna27Xp0KWeEYLveIyA80/wcghvwz5HenTCmUVbgqShHnUEBDo599jRPb/zgqAxfWDnjSutPrUYr1vX1GC2lCbxvN8ws)):

```
pair_list = []
try:
    i = 0
    while True:
        i = tokens.index('#', i)
        j = tokens.index('#', i + 1)
        pair_list.append(tokens[i+1 : j])
        i = j + 1
except ValueError:
    pass
```